# hazelcast helm template, how do i pass my hazelcast.xml?

Tags: kubernetes, hazelcast, kubernetes-helm

Helm greenhorn. I have to "inject" a specific `hazelcast.xml` into the `configMap` with the [chart](https://github.com/hazelcast/charts/tree/master/stable/hazelcast%20helm). I am supposed to `--set` `hazelcast.configurationFiles`

I've tried several ways:

1. ```
   helm install stable/hazelcast --set cluster.memberCount=3 --set hazelcast.configurationFiles[0].val="$(cat k8s/hazelcast.xml)"
   ```
2. ```
   helm install --name=ciao stable/hazelcast --set cluster.memberCount=3 --set hazelcast.configurationFiles[0]="\{ key: hazelcast.xml, val:$(cat k8s/hazelcast.xml)  \}"
   ```
3. ```
   helm install --name=ciao stable/hazelcast --set cluster.memberCount=3   --set hazelcast.configurationFiles[0]="$(cat k8s/hazelcast.xml)"
   ```

none of them works, and i couldn't find or understand how to correctly do it.

I expect that i get `configMap` correctly configured like it should be:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: hazelcast-configuration
data:
  hazelcast.xml: |-
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>........
```

instead of this (closest result obtained with try nr 3):

```
 data:
 "0": |-
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Following the [README](https://github.com/hazelcast/charts/blob/master/stable/hazelcast/README.md) example

you need to uncomment the configurationFiles on values and put paste your own xml file conten:

```
configurationFiles:
hazelcast.xml: |-
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <hazelcast xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-config-3.10.xsd"
                 xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <properties>
      <property name="hazelcast.discovery.enabled">true</property>
    </properties>
    <network>
      <join>
        <multicast enabled="false"/>
        <tcp-ip enabled="false" />
        <discovery-strategies>
          <discovery-strategy enabled="true" class="com.hazelcast.kubernetes.HazelcastKubernetesDiscoveryStrategy">
          </discovery-strategy>
        </discovery-strategies>
      </join>
    </network>

    <management-center enabled="${hazelcast.mancenter.enabled}">${hazelcast.mancenter.url}</management-center>

    <!-- Custom Configuration Placeholder -->
  </hazelcast>
```

but if you don't want to past the content insede the `values.yaml` you can use. File to get the content of a file in the same path

```
configurationFiles:
  hazelcast.xml: |-
  {{ .Files.Get "hazelcast.xml" | indent 4}}
```

[Template guide](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files.md)

Remember you can copy the original `values.yaml` from the chart and use `-f` to specify you own values instead of using `--set` every time.

Comment: Thanks, your last sentence made me learn thanks. passing the -p  files like in openshift templates helps ;) since the configMap.yaml has this syntax for the configurationFiles, it should be possible to pass it with a --set, and i was intrested on how it is the syntax to pass this. I accomplished to pass the file with cat, but not correctly, with the correct syntax, any suggestion ?

Comment: @Tama please, try something from [this documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#set)